# Expand various bootstrap collapse div from another page

Tags: javascript, php, hash, anchor

I have 2 php files.  This is the first file:  services.php

```
<a href="#services1" data-collapse-group="servicesgroup" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services1">
<div class="button-blue">Learn More</div>
</a>

<a href="#services2" data-collapse-group="servicesgroup" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services2">
<div class="button-blue">Learn More</div>
</a>

<div class="solutions">
  <div id="services1" class="collapse" >
    <section> CONTENT </section>
    <section> MORE CONTENT </section>
  </div>

  <div id="services2" class="collapse" >
    <section> CONTENT </section>
    <section> MORE CONTENT </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second file index.php has two web banners that must link:

1st Web banner links to services.php#services1

2nd Web banner links to services.php#services2

When I click on the 1st web banner in index.php, I need it to ONLY expand the #services1 collapsible div.

When I click on the 2nd web banner in index.php, I need it to ONLY expand the #services2 collapsible div.

My current Javascript function being used to expand/collapse from buttons within services.php:

```
//Bootstrap Collapse Group from within Page

$("[data-collapse-group='servicesgroup']").click(function () {
var $this = $(this);
$("[data-collapse-group='servicesgroup']:not([data-target='" +  
$this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
    $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
});
});


//Bootstrap Scroll Up

$("div").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".solutions").offset(500).top},
    'slow');
});
```

Semi Functioning Javascript for Linking from Another Page:

This is the only Javascript that I have found that seems to semi-work because when I click on a web banner on index.php it opens collapsible div's on the services.php page but then the function of my buttons on services.php do not expand or collapse my divs. Also it opens up ALL the collapsible divs, when I need it to open its respective collapsible div (i.e. #services1 or #services2 when the first or second web banner on index.php is clicked)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".collapse").hide();

$(".solutions").click(function () {

    $(this).next(".collapse").slideToggle(400);
});    

if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash.replace("#", "") == "services1"){
    $('.collapse').show();  
}
```

});

I am a novice to javascript so I will need a step-by-step explanation or exact copy and paste code, please.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$(window.location.hash).collapse('show');`

Comment: @cmorrissey I saw your response and used it like this but it does not open up any of the collapsible div's:  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".collapse").hide();

    $(".solutions").click(function () {

        $(this).next(".collapse").slideToggle(400);
    });    
    
    $(window.location.hash).collapse('show'); 
    }

});

Comment: Its because you are not using the bootstrap collapse correctly in your js in the first place, review the documentation, you should be using `.collapse` for all instances not `.hide` or `.slideToggle`

Comment: @cmorrissey Oh ok. Thank you. I'll have to give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: @cmorrissey For some reason when I use  `$(window.location.hash).collapse('show');`  it does not work.  When I use  `$(window.location.hash).toggle();`  it works.  It takes me directly from the index.php to the services.php#anchor and expands it correctly.  My issue is that when I click on one of the other collapse buttons (button-blue) on the services.php page to expand  another section on the same page and collapse the `(window.location.hash)` that was opened `(window.location.hash)` stays open and does not collapse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention I simplified the code to:                    `$(document).ready(function () {
     $(window.location.hash).toggle();
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jesus!!! After much searching on this site and multiple sites on the topic of Bootstrap collapse div opening from an external link (another page) and finding no results the following worked:

1. **Code works for:**  External Page Link to expand Collapse DIV on another page BUT will NOT hide the Collapse DIV when clicking on
   other collapse buttons on same page:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window.location.hash).show();
   });
   ```
2. **Code works for:** External Page Link to expand Collapse DIV on another page AND will hide the Collapse DIV when clicking on other
   collapse buttons. Collapse function of other buttons work correctly:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window.location.hash).addClass('collapse in');
   });
   ```
3. First file (index.php) containing multiple Links to Collapse DIV Anchors on another page:

   ```
   LINKED IMAGE: services.php#services1
   LINKED IMAGE: services.php#services2
   LINKED IMAGE: services.php#services3
   ```
4. Second file (services.php) containing Collapse DIVS:  services.php

   ```
   <a href="#services1" data-collapse-group="servicesgroup" data-  
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#services1">
   <div class="button-blue">Learn More</div>
   </a>

   <a href="#services2" data-collapse-group="servicesgroup" data-
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#services2">
   <div class="button-blue">Learn More</div>
   </a>

   <a href="#services3" data-collapse-group="servicesgroup" data-
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#services2">
   <div class="button-blue">Learn More</div>
   </a>

   <div class="solutions">
      <div id="services1" class="collapse" >
        <section> CONTENT </section>
        <section> MORE CONTENT </section>
      </div>

      <div id="services2" class="collapse" >
       <section> CONTENT </section>
       <section> MORE CONTENT </section>
      </div>

      <div id="services3" class="collapse" >
       <section> CONTENT </section>
       <section> MORE CONTENT </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   ```
5. Third file (services.js) contains current Javascript function being used to expand/collapse from buttons within services.php:

   ```
   //Expand Collapse DIV from External Link and Internal Collapse buttons work

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window.location.hash).addClass('collapse in');
   });

   //Collapse DIV Group from within Page

   $("[data-collapse-group='servicesgroup']").click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   $("[data-collapse-group='servicesgroup']:not([data-target='" +  
   $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
   $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
     });
   });


   //Scroll Up DIV when clicking on Collapse Button within page

   $("div").click(function() {
   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".solutions").offset(500).top},
     'slow');
   });
   ```